# Changing color according to seek bar value

Tags: android, colors, seekbar

I am trying to change color according to value of seek bar. I'd like colors to appear in wide range.

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't give me colors I want:

```
seekBarColor.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int progress = 0;
          @Override
          public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
            progress = progresValue;
            int lower = Color.argb(0xFF,progress*0x10000, progress*0x100, progress)+0xff000000;
            color.setBackgroundColor(lower);
          }

          @Override
          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
              db.updateColor("");
          }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to obtain colors from color circle? because by your code I suppose you get gray shades

Comment: yes i want to generate color from color circle and yes my code returns only gray and i can't fix it

Comment: Then use HSV color instead of RGB. Below I provided a code snippet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need only bright, saturated colors, use `Color.HSVToColor()` instead of setting R, G and B components directly:

```
float[] hsvColor = {0, 1, 1};
// generate only hue component in range [0, 360),
// leaving saturation and brightness maximum possible
hsvColor[0] = 360f * progress / maxProgress;
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsvColor));
```

This code will set color starting from red, then change smoothly to orange, yellow, green, blue and magenta back to red as `progress` is changing from `0` to `maxProgress`

Comment: to which value should i set max progress to ?

Comment: @SarahSami it your progress starts on 0 and ends on 100, then to 100.

Comment: why i can't get any values of black color ?

Comment: @SarahSami because black color has hsv values {0, 0, 0}. First you need to determine which kind of route through 3D color space you want to obtain. From black to white through gray shades is one possible way, from red to red through various colors of color circle is another way... actually, they can be different.

Comment: @SarahSami first you need to decide which color should be starting, which should be ending, and how color chould change in intermediate points. Solutions will be different.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou can u pls help me how can i show three different range with 3 colors in seekbar like "underweight" , "normal" ,"over weight" , "obese" with 4 different colors in circular seekbar android

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass 0-255 values to `Color.argb(int,int,int,int)` method.

This might work?

```
Color.argb(0xFF, progress, progress, progress) //will return some gray color based on progress.
```

You might have to scale your progress value based on the min and max value.
For example if you have progress `0-100` then you should calculate your color values with `progress * 255 / 100`

Comment: but i don't want to get gray only , i want to generate all color from color circle

Comment: Well, I don't know how your color cirle works, but you surely have to adjust the red, green, blue values passed to `Color.argb` function, based on the position where the user touches your View.
Btw, if you are using full alpha, you can use `Color.rgb` function, which returns RGB color with full alpha (255).