# Change background colour via seek bar using HSV colour scale

Tags: android

I am using some code from here [Changing color according to seek bar value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043321/change-background-color-according-to-seek-bar-value-in-android) to change the colour using HSV colour chart:

```
        private void updateBackgroundColor(int sliding) {

        int maxProgress = 100; //bars max progress

        float[] hsvRed = { 0, 1,  1 };
        hsvRed[0] = 180f * sliding / maxProgress;
        redView.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsvRed));
```

I also have one for blue which doesn't work and I have tried several different values:

```
        float[] hsvBlue = { 0, (float) 1, (float) 0.5 };
        hsvBlue[2] = 180f * sliding / maxProgress;
        blueView.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsvBlue));
```

My question is how do I go about finding out what values to put in the formula for the HSV colours for specific colours (yellow, green and blue). As far as I am aware, blue is {240, 100, 100} and red is {0, 100, 100} but it doesn't fit the above formula. Can someone explain please? It seems the array values must be between 0 - 1.

Comment: http://www.google.com/m?q=hsv+to+rgb&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new

Comment: @pskink I have done that already, the above formula does not work if I use the correct values of HSV Colour, for example Red is { 0, 100, 100 } but in above formula it is { 0, 1, 1 } and blue is {240, 100, 100 } But it seems that it will only work for one colour Red.

Comment: hsv[1] & hsv[2] are in [0..1] range,  read the docs

Comment: I see, so that formula won't really work on other colours.

Comment: it works, just divide saturation and value by 100